# Stolen Tefillin Fund

Tags: tefilin, tzedakah-charity, gezel-stealing

My tefillin have gone missing, as well as a tallit which had belonged to my grandfather ז”ל. At present, I still hope that they turn up, however I am trying to look into other options if chas veshalom they don't.

Since one of the possibilities is that they were stolen, my question is: is there a fund to replace tefillin which were stolen?

**EDIT: B"H My tallit and tefillin were found earlier today!**

Comment: Why would such a thing exist?

Comment: Perhaps find a tefilling gemach that can lend you tefillin until you can purchase new ones. Consider adding a personal articles policy to your homeowners or renters insurance to cover the tefillin (like with a diamond ring). Some homeowners, rental, or auto policies cover personal articles depending on where they were stolen from.

Comment: For possible help, also e-mail me at Davidariel25@gmail.com TY

Comment: @sabbahillel, do you know a Boston-area tefillin gemach? If I were renting or living in my own place (or had a car) I'd gladly add such a policy, however there is not such thing in my dorm contract AFAIK.

Comment: @GershonGold, I'm going to wait a few more days before I act as if they were stolen. I am trying to track them down still and I don't want to give up on the chance of finding them, b'ezrat Hashem.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt It might be a separate renters policy. You would need to call a local insurance agent and ask. Perhaps the an agent for the insurance company your parents use would give you a better deal.

Comment: If they don't turn up, definitely find out if they are already covered on your/parents' home insurance since it's pretty typical that they would be.

Comment: @GershonGold, My tefillin are no longer missing!

Comment: @DavidKenner, courtesy tag ^

Comment: Great. I am thrilled for you.

Comment: How does that update the question? The question is still the same AFAICT

Comment: @DoubleAA, while it no longer affects me, it is still a question which should be answered so that if chas veshalom this happens to someone else, there is a solution.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Yes... so?